# WebApi GET Troubleshooting 400 BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When making a call to my webapi running locally, I am passing data in the requestUri as base64 encoded Json of my serialized object, but getting StatusCode 400 at every turn.

How do I fix my request?

```
public class VerifyController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Verify/jsonStringAddressOriginal
    public AddressResult Get(string base64AddressOriginal)
```

The caller:

```
var requestUri = string.Format("api/verify/{0}", base64address);
Console.WriteLine("requestUri:\n{0}", requestUri);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
```

requestUri:

```
api/verify/eyJDb21wYW55IjoiIiwiQWRkcmVzcyI6Ijc3NTAgQmVsZm9ydCBQYXJrd2F5IDIwMCIsI
kFkZHJlc3MyIjoiIiwiU3VpdGUiOiIiLCJDaXR5IjoiSmFja3NvbnZpbGxlIiwiU3RhdGUiOiJGTCIsI
lppcCI6IjMyMjU2IiwiUGx1czQiOiIiLCJMYXN0TGluZSI6IiIsIkNvdW50cnlDb2RlIjoiIiwiVXJiY
W5pemF0aW9uIjoiIiwiTGFzdE5hbWUiOiIiLCJQYXJzZWRBZGRyZXNzUmFuZ2UiOiIiLCJQYXJzZWRQc
mVEaXJlY3Rpb24iOiIiLCJQYXJzZWRTdHJlZXROYW1lIjoiIiwiUGFyc2VkU3VmZml4IjoiIiwiUGFyc
2VkUG9zdERpcmVjdGlvbiI6IiIsIlBhcnNlZFN1aXRlTmFtZSI6IiIsIlBhcnNlZFN1aXRlUmFuZ2UiO
iIiLCJQYXJzZWRSb3V0ZVNlcnZpY2UiOiIiLCJQYXJzZWRMb2NrQm94IjoiIiwiUGFyc2VkRGVsaXZlc
nlJbnN0YWxsYXRpb24iOiIifQ==
Error code: BadRequest
Reason: Bad Request
```

I think it's a malformed request but I don't know in what way. There seem to be no further properties of the response object detailing which error that the 400 Status Code represents.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179357.aspx

This is my first WebApi so when answering, make no assumptions about my configuration.
VS2013 update 3, Web Api, using an HttpClient as the caller.

Comment: Would the == on the end of the Uri cause this?  Hmm, maybe I need to UrlEncode the base64.

Comment: That sounds like very likely. I'm curious if that resolved your problem.

Comment: No joy.  I trimmed the two equals off the end, still getting BadRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't count the number of characters in your URI, but very long URIs (> 2000 characters) are likely to cause problems. Try making this a POST request and putting the base64 data into the request body.

Comment: 507 characters.  I considered that.  POST would not be RESTful either?  I'm just passing a value (address) and wanting a value (cleansed address) back.

Comment: I disagree about POST not being RESTful. GET in REST terms has very clearly defined semantics and means "give me a resource that already exists on the server". I assume that the URL with the base64 string semantically doesn't address a pre-existing resource, does it?

Comment: Agreed, that's what I'm doing, passing a bad address and asking the server to give me a good one that already exists in the USPS data files.  I'm not creating or updating anything new on server that might justify POST.

Comment: Well, POST, unlike PUT, doesn't necessarily have to update or create anything. The semantics of POST are not so narrowly defined. Besides, I wouldn't be too purist about REST up to the point where it gets in your way.

Comment: Looks like you right about the length.  When requestUri.Length is 255 it succeeds, after thatit starts failing.  So using empirical evidence, 255 must be the max length string passed to Httpclient.GetAsync(string) that won't cause BadRequest.  I guess this will have to be a POST.

Comment: Well, I am baffled by this myself, because in my experience URIS with < 2000 chars are never a problem. Anyway, I still think POST semantically isn't less appropriate than GET. Sending a large-ish base64 string IMHO is more likely to have "sending data" than "retrieving a uniquely identified resource" semantics.

Comment: Also, if the data you are sending is supposed to be confidential, putting it in the URI is a security hole.